# Pine script label

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I use this code

```
label.new(bar_index, bar_index, str.tostring(bar_index))
```

Strange thing is that TradingView don't print the label until the is value 1140 or above.

I can't figure out why the label is not displayed from bar_index 0 and forward.

I have tried the code both as an indicator and as a strategy. None of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on how many labels you can have on your chart.

You can set this with the `max_labels_count` argument in your `indicator()` or `strategy()` call. The default value is 50.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much. I see that 500 labels seems to be max on a chart.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you exceed the limit, the old ones will be deleted. That's why you don't see any labels where `bar_index < 1140`.